# Upgrading from 3.4 to 4: Parameter names will be made case sensitive in Symfony 4.0

Tags: symfony

```
User Deprecated: Parameter names will be made case sensitive in Symfony 4.0.
Using "httpprotocol" instead of "httpProtocol" is deprecated since Symfony 3.4.
```

I don't understand where this is coming from in my code. I am about to upgrade Symfony from 3.4 to 4, but this deprecation must be solved first. is httpprotocol just an example? I can not find that value in my code.

Comment: Did you search through vendor as well?  It's not in the standard Symfony distribution but might be in some other third party bundle.

Comment: Yes, nothing there. Am I getting it right that the parameters should not be lowercase? Is this just parameters in .yml files?

Comment: It just means that parameter names are now case sensitive in S4.  I have never seen this particular message before.  If you search for "Parameter names" under var/cache/dev you will find where the message is generated.  It certainly implies that you have httpProtocol as well as httpprotocol somewhere in your code.  The actual case does not matter.  It is basically just a warning that in S4 httpProtocol and httpprotocol are two different parameters.

Answer (score 2):

I had a parameter defined in the config.yml:

```
parameters:
    locale: en
    httpProtocol: http
```

and referenced in routes.yml

```
route:
    schemes:  ['%httpProtocol%']
```

I changed all of the httpProtocol parameters to `http_protocol` which seems to have solved the issue. The deprecation notice message was a bit misleading though.